# How to solve error in SP Flash Tool?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, unbricking

My operating system: **Artix Linux**

My image fastboot: **XIAOMI REDMI NOTE 9 (MERLIN) MIUI V13.0.2.0 ANDROID 12.0** (merlin_global_images_V13.0.2.0.SJOMIXM_20221013.0000.00_12.0_global)

Phone: **Xiaomi Redmi Note 9**

Go to folder bypass. And run command:

```
sudo python main.py
```

I got output:

```
[2023-06-16 22:33:10.319185] Waiting for device
[2023-06-16 22:33:38.939744] Found port = /dev/ttyACM0
[2023-06-16 22:33:39.045127] Device hw code: 0x707
[2023-06-16 22:33:39.045223] Device hw sub code: 0x8a00
[2023-06-16 22:33:39.045265] Device hw version: 0xca00
[2023-06-16 22:33:39.045301] Device sw version: 0x0
[2023-06-16 22:33:39.045336] Device secure boot: True
[2023-06-16 22:33:39.045372] Device serial link authorization: True
[2023-06-16 22:33:39.045406] Device download agent authorization: True
[2023-06-16 22:33:39.045440] Disabling watchdog timer
[2023-06-16 22:33:39.045971] Disabling protection
[Errno 5] Input/Output Error
[2023-06-16 22:33:40.403658] Payload did not reply
```

lsusb output (after bypass):

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0e8d:0003 MediaTek Inc. MT6227 phone
```

Now I run SP Flash Tool v5.2228.00 with command:

```
sudo ./flash_tool.sh
```

I got that error after clicking download:

```
ERROR : STATUS_BROM_CMD_STARTCMD_FAIL (-1073348607) , MSP ERROE CODE : 0x00.
```

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Looks like `-1073348607` is `0xC0060001` in hexadecimal. There's [a thread on XDA for the same error code](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/brom-error-status_brom_cmd_startcmd_fail-0xc0060001.3651632/), or otherwise read another solution from [the linked forum post](https://www.hovatek.com/forum/thread-439.html). Let us know the result, or feel free to post an answer if it solves the issue. Good luck!